# Can not install Open SSH server

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, passwd

I can not install OpenSSH server.

My command to install:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

And I got the following error:

[image]

Raw output error:

```
chage: /etc/passwd.15967: Permission denied
chage: cannot lock /etc/passwd.trY again leter•

Stopped: ./usrbin/chage -X 99999 sshd returned error code 1.

Removing user sshd...

dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess install post-installation script returned error e

Setting up ssh-import-id
Processing triggers far systemd (229-4ubuntu21.21)
Processing triggers for ureadahead
Processing triggers for ufw

Errors were encountered while processing: openssh-server

E: Sub-processer /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried some following solutions:

- `mount -o remount,rw /` => but no luck
- I edited file `/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
 password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
```

but no luck

- My `/etc/passwd`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2527
```

Output of `df /etc`

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4      131793388 39254516  86848820  32% /
```

Please help!

Comment: Please provide the output of `df /etc`. // Also, please don’t post screenshots of text. They’re not searchable or accessible. Instead, copy the text and put it a code block.

Comment: Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4      131793388 39254516  86848820  32% /

You can see img here: https://imgur.com/a/e6sA1iD

Comment: Like I said: No images. Instead, update your question with the new information. Please also add `df -i /etc` while you’re at it.

Comment: @DanielB Thank my friend, I just typing the error with my mobile phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the `/etc/ssh` directory is created. If not, create it with `sudo mkdir /etc/ssh`

After creating it, do this :

`sudo apt-get purge openssh-server openssh-client
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client`

Comment: Still got error same above

Comment: Did you create the `ssh` directory? And can you show us your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: yes I create `ssh` directory already

Comment: What do you have in `sources.list` ?

Comment: My `sources.list` is fine, I think, I do not have output at the moment, but I think the main error here is the line: `chage: /etc/passwd Permission denied`

Comment: not in my case, I gave up

Comment: Thanks, did work for me. Only had to run both commands.